# Как в reportviewer скрыть строку в шапке таблицы, если это не первая страница?

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

Всем привет!

Кто нибудь знает как в reportviewer скрыть строку в шапке таблицы, если это не первая страница?

Т.е. есть таблица, у неё есть шапка таблицы (header) из двух строк, для того что бы шапка(header) повторялась на следующих страницах установлено свойство **Repeat header columns on each page**, но необходимо на следующих страницах повторять не всю шапку, а только одну строку из шапки.

Вот этот ответ не помог:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174648/hide-row-if-it-is-not-on-the-first-page